# steps to connect play framework 2.5.x-java to mysql database

Tags: windows

Please am completely new in play framework and have read several tuts but still have some problems. Please could some one help me list the steps and file to be edited in order to establish a connect to mysql db with play framework 2.5.x-java not scala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 :
Config connection with mySql. In `conf/application.conf` file

```
  ebean.default = ["models.*"] // this is your entity folder
  db {
  default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  default.url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/YourDBName"
  default.username=yourUserName
  default.password="yourPass"
}
```

And my project look like

[image: And my project look like]